# Can we conclude, with the strong law of large numbers, that $n$ random variables are independent?

Tags: probability, distributions, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose we have a sequence of identically distributed random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, and that we *know* $(X_1 + \ldots + X_n)/n$ converges almost surely to $\mu = E[X]$ as $n$ approaches infinity. Can we conclude that the random variables are independent?

Comment: "identically distributed random variables" = they have the same marginal distribution?

Comment: Suppose for simplicity that they're all Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$. Here's an example where they are not independent: either all trials succeed or all trials fail, so $(X_1 + \ldots + X_n)/n$ does not converge almost surely to $E[X] = p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No and here is a simple counterexample:  flip a single coin and let $Y = 1$ if the coin is a head and $Y = -1$ otherwise.  Now set $X_n = Y$ if $n$ is odd and $X_n = - Y$ if $n$ is even.  The $X_n$ all have the same distribution and $(X_1 + \ldots + X_n) / n$ converges to zero with probability one, but they are not independent.